# View devices with bluetooth range windows 7 mobile c#

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

How do I get a list of bluetooth devices in range?

Thanks
Sp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third party developers do not, currently, have access to bluetooth APIs on Windows Phone 7.

There is, therefore, no way to currently do this.

Hopefully the ability to do this will be made available in a future update to the SDK.